# How to change the font size dynamically using autolayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I want to change the font size dynamically for each device using code for each device.I know  can do it using size class/But i don't want to use size class.

Answer (score 0):

```
@property int fontSize;

+(NSString *)getDeviceModel
{
    //Device Model
    NSString *phoneModel = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
    return phoneModel;
}

- (void)setLabelFontSize {
    NSString *hardware = [self getDeviceModel];
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"]) {
        self.fontSize = 10.0
    }else if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,1"]) {
        self.fontSize = 14.0
    }
    [_timeLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:self.fontSize]];
}
```

//I only list two device models, you can get other models through the Internet.

Comment: well this approach is not good.Why should check for all devices.Is there any other way?I have already done through this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Provide aspect ratio constraint to uilabel, It will automatically handle font size.

Comment: Why? It will increase uilabel size/font automatically

Comment: what if i don't wan to provide aspect ratio.

Comment: then you have to check device type and do it with programatically.

Comment: Ok. i think there would be a better way of doing it.

Comment: may be if u found let me know

Answer (score 0):

You may change font size base on **size classes**. Below link will help you regarding this. [Font size using size class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/ChangingtheFontforaSizeClass.html).
Thanks

Comment: i don't see each size class for diffrent models of iPhone

Comment: Do you have idea about size classes?

Comment: Yes.I know about them

Comment: Try with below link which help you to define size class base on device. [Size classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html)